# Using Map Reports (.rdlc) in mvc5

Tags: dictionary, shapefile, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a shapefile map showing it as a Report(.rdlc) in mvc5

Like a photo:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYf4a.jpg)

**How can I display this file (Report(.rdlc)) as a map with Bing Map Layer in view?**

Can anyone help me?

Does anyone have code or educational link?